# Converting Obj C to Swift Error:type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've been using an objC framework in my swift project so I'm converting an objC method to swift. The objC method is as follows:

```
[[MySingleton sharedInstance] provisionUserWithPIN:pin
                                               organizationID:kOrgID
                                                  accessToken:kOrgToken
                                                   completion:^(NSString *UID, User *user) {
 }];
```

My swift conversion is:

```
 MySingleton.sharedInstance().provisionUserWithPIN(pin, organizationID: kOrgID, accessToken: kOrgToken) {(UID: String, user: User) in
    }
```

I'm getting an Error:type of expression is ambiguous without more context pointed after the ( in provisionUserWithPIN.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Been stuck with this for hours.

Declaration:

```
- (void)provisionUserWithPIN:(NSString *)PIN organizationID:(NSString *)organizationID accessToken:(NSString *)accessToken completion:(void (^)(NSString *UID, User *user))completion;
```

Comment: Can you also post the Objective-C declaration of that method?

Comment: @patrickLynch Added the declaration:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that a parameter declared like this in Objective-C

```
(NSString *)something
```

does **not** becomes this in Swift

```
something:String
```

but it actually is translated into this:

```
something:String!
```

So you can invoke your Objective-C method in Swift writing

```
    MySingleton.sharedInstance().provisionUserWithPIN(
        "pin",
        organizationID: "orgID",
        accessToken: "accessTken") { (UID: String!, user: User!) -> () in

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: SWEET!!! Thanks man! I just hate the error in swift. It doesn't make any sense to me. Thanks for pointing that out. You saved my ass today.